# Bind ActiveMQResourceAdapter to custom Work Manager in Weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.13.0.redhat-00006 for messaging. I've deployed the ActiveMQ Artemis JCA RA in Weblogic.

I am facing the requirement to prioritize messages to be executed from Weblogic. I would like to utilize work manager concept provided by Weblogic. I have created 2 domain scoped work managers in Weblogic:

1. `WorkManagerHighPriority`
2. `WorkManagerLowPriority`

I am trying to patch ActiveMQ, so that it utilizes my custom work manager(e.g. `WorkManagerLowPriority`), instead of the default work manager.  I found this method in `ActiveMQResourceAdapter`:

```java
public WorkManager getWorkManager() {
    if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        logger.trace("getWorkManager()");
    }

    if (ctx == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return ctx.getWorkManager();
}
```

In my naive thinking I modified this method to:

```java
public WorkManager getWorkManager() {
    if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        logger.trace("getWorkManager()");
    }

    InitialContext ic = null;
    WorkManager wm = null;
    try {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        // WebLogic Server 10.x/12.x connection details
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:28010");
        ic = new InitialContext(env);
        wm = (WorkManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/wm/WorkManagerLowPriority");
        if (wm == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return wm;
}
```

Everything was working fine. However, after deploying this patch I get these errors:

```
"message": "Not an ActiveMQ Artemis Destination:ActiveMQQueue[online.eingabe.MyQueue]",
"name": "javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException",
"extendedStackTrace": "javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Not an ActiveMQ Artemis Destination:ActiveMQQueue
```

Additionally, I continuously get this warning:

```
"extendedStackTrace":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/collection/IntObjectHashMap$2
   at io.netty.util.collection.IntObjectHashMap.values(IntObjectHashMap.java:221)
```

Questions:

1. Is it generally possible to achieve my goal so that ActiveMQ uses a custom work manager instead of the default work manager?
2. Am I on the right track by modifying `ActiveMQResourceAdapter.getWorkManager()` in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: Hallo Justin,  yes, I have a succesfully integrated ActiveMQ in Weblogic, as rar depoymnt, it is working fine.  I also have all the queues configured.  It is a 2.13.0.redhat-00006.  I somehow dont know where I should start to patch the ActiveMQ resource adapter.  I do have this general information from Java EE Spec:When the resource adapter is deployed, the start() method is invoked. When it is undeployed, the stop() method is called. Any work that the resource adapter initiates can be performed in the start() method as with a WebLogic Server startup class.

Comment: I can find the start method in ActiveMQResourceAdapter, but I dont know when the resource adapter starts to get the weblogic work manager.

Comment: It's interesting that you've gotten this to work with the JCA RA from ActiveMQ Artemis 2.13.0 as only recently support for admin objects was added. See [ARTEMIS-2903](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2903) for more details on that.

Comment: The ActiveMQ Artemis JCA RA gets the work manager from the container by using `javax.resource.spi.BootstrapContext.getWorkManager()`. The `BootstrapContext` instance is provided by Weblogic to the RA via the `start()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this approach is ultimately viable. If you're just trying to hack something together as a proof of concept in the development phase then maybe this makes sense, but deploying a custom patched version of the ActiveMQ Artemis JCA resource adapter to one or more production systems for an enterprise-grade solution is almost certainly going to cause head-aches later.

It's important to note that the `ctx` variable used by the ActiveMQ Artemis JCA RA  here is a `javax.resource.spi.BootstrapContext` which is provided *by the container* (i.e. Weblogic) to the RA when it starts. The RA uses this `BootstrapContext` to get the work manager from the container. So, ultimately the container is providing the work manager implementation to the RA. If you want to use a different work manager then *this* is where the change needs to happen.

I know very little about Weblogic, but I imagine it has a way to configure the actual work manager implementation that is used here. I recommend you investigate what configuration options that Weblogic provides. It wouldn't make a lot of sense for a container to allow multiple work managers without also providing a way to supply those to the various Java EE applications that need them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same issue like hingiswiss.
I observed, that it's possible, that den RA uses a workmanager from weblogic, to get the message out of the queue.

But it seems, that the RA is always making its own threads to call the MDB, is that right? The threads are named something like "ActiveMQ-client-factory-threads-316821716" and are created by the ActiveMQThreadFactory.

I found no way to configure the RA, so that it uses the threads from a workmanager which is managed by weblogic to call the MDB.

Comment: yes, it seems like it is not possible to let weblogic-threads used in ActiveMQ, since ActiveMQ creates its own thread pool to operate, which is fine and ok.  But to be honest, using ActiveMQ in scope of application server, I rather find this suboptimal, because the application server should be the one, who manages the threads being used.  Perhaps this only applies on weblogic.

Comment: To be more precise, in the mean while, I found out that ActiveMQResourceAdapter.java is not the class to modify for the requirement.  The Work manager being used in that class is mainly to perform initial calls of life cycle methods during the deployment of the RA, such as activateEndpoint(...).  The creation of the its own thread pool is somewhere else in broker code.